# In Python/Pandas, Check if a comma separated string contains any value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Code
----
ABC,DEF,XYZ
ABC,XYZ
...
...
CBA,FED,ABC
```

I'm trying to check if this series of comma separated string contains any string in my below list:

["UVW","XYZ"]

I know we can check single value like "XYZ" in df["Code"] but how can we do it for a list of values in Python or is there any special functions from pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.contains` with `regex=True`:

Given `Series`, `s` and target list `l`:

```
s 
0    ABC,DEF,XYZ
1        ABC,XYZ
2    CBA,FED,ABC

l = ["UVW","XYZ"]

s.str.contains('|'.join(l))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```